# Rails helper method seems to be killing my JQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

My application allows a user to make a list with different categories. While making a list, if the user decides they would like another category, they may create one without leaving the page. The new category will appear in the list, and the user can begin adding items to it.

My issue seems to be that adding any Rails helpers (link_to, render) to my 'new.js.erb' file, it stops the script from doing it's thing. My new div and dropdown menu are not rendered. I get no errors on the console or the server logs. Just nothing. If I remove these methods, everything works fine.

```
function addCategory(){
    var lastCategory = '<%= current_user.categories[-2].name %>';
    console.log(lastCategory);
    $('#' + lastCategory).after("<h3 class='category'><%= @category.name %></h3>\
                                <div class='dropdown-button' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#<%= @category.name %>'>\
                                  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'></span>\
                                </div>\
                                <div id='<%= @category.name %>' class='collapse'>\
                                  <h4>Create a new item here:</h4>\
                                  <div id='append<%= @category.id %>'></div>\
                                  <%= link_to 'Home', root_url %>\ //does not work!
                                </div>");
}
```

It's just the link_to and other methods that seem to be causing a problem. All other erb tags <%= %> seem to work and render appropriately.

My goal is to render a form and a link in this newly rendered dropdown section, but since the root of the problem seems to be Rails methods in general, I added a link_to home for clarity.

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Nope, nothing in the server logs either. Inspector shows no new divs have been added. 

Once I remove the link_to helper, it all works fine though.

Answer (score 1):

Damnit, I figured it out. Forget to add 'j' to my rails helpers to convert them to JavaScript

```
<%= j link_to "Home", root_url %>
```